# change the input value of a text field based on the two other inputs

Tags: javascript

I want to add the value from the number input to the first text input when select 'Yes' from the dropdown menu. For example, if 'ABCD' is put into the text input and 'Yes' is selected and 1 is in the number input, then the text input will be ABCD-1.

```
   <input type="text" name="pr" id="pr" />
   <select  class="form-control" name ="rt" id="rt">
   <option value = "0" selected>No</option>
   <option value = "1">Yes</option>
   </select>
    <input type="number" name="at" id="at"/>

    <script>
    $('#pr, #rt, #at').change(function(){
    var pr1 = document.getElementById('#pr').value
    var rt1 = document.getElementById('#rt').value;
    var at1 = document.getElementById('#at').value;

    var rr = pr+at;

    if(rt1 == 1){
        $pr.value = rr;
    }else{
        $pr.value = pr1;
    }

    });
   </script>
```

Comment: You do not need the `#` when you are using `document.getElementById`

Comment: We need to pause and discuss these variable names. Friend, I have no idea what you're getting at with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const firstInput = document.getElementById('firstInput');
const secondInput = document.getElementById('secondInput');
const selectInput = document.getElementById('selectInput');

selectInput.addEventListener('change', e => {
  if(e.target.value == 1) {
    firstInput.value += '-' + secondInput.value;
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="pr" id="firstInput" />
<br/>
<input type="number" name="at" id="secondInput"/><br/>

<select  class="form-control" name ="rt" id="selectInput">
  <option value = "0" selected>No</option>
  <option value = "1">Yes</option>
</select>
```

Here is the modified solution:

```
<input type="text" name="pr" id="firstInput" />
<br/>
<input type="number" name="at" id="secondInput"/><br/>

<select  class="form-control" name ="rt" id="selectInput">
  <option value = "0" selected>No</option>
  <option value = "1">Yes</option>
</select>

<script>
    const firstInput = document.getElementById('firstInput');
    const secondInput = document.getElementById('secondInput');
    const selectInput = document.getElementById('selectInput');

    selectInput.addEventListener('change', e => {
      if(e.target.value == 1) {
        firstInput.value += '-' + secondInput.value;
      }
    });
</script>
```

Works like a charm! Also here is snippet